# How to link SDK to index in DevOps Hub extension

Tags: angular, azure-devops

I'm trying to make an Angular hub extension for devops. My problem is I don't know how to refer the VSS.SDK.min... I followed the [doccumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/get-started/node?view=azure-devops) on microsoft website, but I can't make it work

I tried to make a simple hello Angular app.

Here my  vss-extension.json:

```
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    "id": "theId",
    "publisher": "MyPublisherID",
    "version": "1.0.11",
    "name": "AngularTest",
    "description": "A sample Visual Studio Services extension",
    "public": false,
    "categories": ["Azure Repos"],
    "targets": [
        {
            "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
        }
    ],
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "my-hub",
            "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-code-web.code-hub-group"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "AnguTest",
                "uri": "dist/angularTest/index.html"
            }
        }
    ],
    "files": [
        {
            "path": "dist/angularTest/index.html",
            "addressable": true
        },
        {
            "path": "node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib",
            "addressable": true,
            "packagePath": "lib"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here my Index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="lib/VSS.SDK.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   VSS.init();
        VSS.ready(function() {
            document.getElementById("name").innerText = VSS.getWebContext().user.name;
        });
</script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularTest</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: red">
  <h1>Hello, <span id="name"></span></h1>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try with that I'm getting 2 errors: 
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () for VSS.SDK.min.js 
- index.html:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: VSS is not defined at index.html:6 (normal since the server can't found the js file)

I just want to display the index page. After that I think I will be alright!

Comment: Did you run `npm install vss-web-extension-sdk`?

Comment: Yeah, I have the file there: /node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/lib/VSS.SDK.min.js

Comment: try to specify in the `index.html' <script>` the full path.

Comment: That's just solve the problem with the VSS.SDK.min.js, but I still get the ```index.html:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: VSS is not defined at index.html:6``` , do I need to wait for ```DOM``` to be loaded??? I also got ```Cross-Origin Read Blocking``` on ```https://aex.dev.azure.com/me?mkt=fr-FR```

Comment: Hey @mplourde, did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the "node_modules\vss-web-extension-sdk\lib" to your extension base folder and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, there is a problem on the projects files is being built, and your path ""lib/VSS.SDK.min.js" in your html doesn't point to your javascript location.

My setup is as followed:

My folder structure

```
|-- my-hub.html
|-- node_modules
    |-- ...
|-- sdk
    |-- scripts
        |-- VSS.SDK.min.js
|-- package.json
|-- vss-extension.json
```

My Html src = sdk/script/VSS.SDK.min.js doesn't work.

i managed to solve it with simple tricks:
 1. Use development tool (F12 in Chrome) to see the path being used to look up the js file, i switched to the network tab and look for your VSS.SDK.min.js (type=script), hover around the .js file, and you will be able to see the lookup path, for my case. I noticed it is a "baseurl...sdk/hub/sdk/script/VSS.SDK.min.js", thus, i modified my .html i used "src="../../sdk/script/VSS.SDK.min.js"